# Error in the switch between the activities

Tags: android

I´m having a problem in the switch between the transtition GameOver state to other actitivity.

The error is "App, has stopped" and when i click "OK" the execute what i want.

Can you help me?

The error is in the

"  gameView.updateGameOver();"

Java NullPointerException

```
package com.example.asus.game2d;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GameOverDialog extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //image button

    private Button ButtonOk;
    private GameView gameView;
    private ImageView medaille;
    private ImageButton LogOut;
    private ImageButton SoundOff;
    private ImageButton SoundOn;
    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private int soundID;
    public static boolean play = true;
    public static int Clicked = 0;

    private Context mContext;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ///*********end

        setContentView(R.layout.gameover);

        //setting the orientation to landscape
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);



        ImageView medaille = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.medaille);
        //adding a click listener

        //Define Logout
        ImageButton LogOut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);


        //Define SoundOn

     /*   ImageButton SoundOn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton9);

        //Define SoundOff

        ImageButton SoundOff = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);
        */


        //getting the button
        ImageButton ButtonOk = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton11);

        LogOut.setOnClickListener(this);
       /* SoundOff.setOnClickListener(this);
        SoundOn.setOnClickListener(this);*/
        ButtonOk.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Version

        //define
        TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_current_score);

        TextView txtsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_current_score_value);
        txtsView.setText(String.valueOf(GameView.score));

        //Value
        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_best_score_value);
        myText.setText(String.valueOf(GameView.Highscorer) );

        TextView txtViews = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_best_score);


    }

    /*
    private void soundPlay()
    {
        //* Sounds effects

        // This SoundPool is deprecated but don't worry
        soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

        try {
            // Create objects of the 2 required classes
            AssetManager assetManager = mContext.getAssets();
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;

            // Load our fx in memory ready for use
            descriptor = assetManager.openFd("gameover.wav");

                soundID = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Print an error message to the console
            Log.e("error", "failed to load sound files");
        }
        if(play) {
            soundPool.play(soundID, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        }
    }*/

    @Override
    /*
    public void onClick (View v){
        gameView.lives = 3;
        gameView.run();
    }


    /*
    */

        public void onClick (View v){



        switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.imageButton11:
                    //starting game activity
                   gameView.updateGameOver();





                    break;

                case R.id.imageButton4:
                    //Logout
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, GameLogout.class));
                    // do your code
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButton8:
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, GameLogout.class));
                    break;
               /*case R.id.imageButton9:
                    play = false;
                    SoundOn.setVisibility(View.GONE);//set visibility to false on create
                    SoundOff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButton10:*/
                    /*play = true;
                    SoundOn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//set visibility to false on create
                    SoundOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                    */



            }

        }

}
```

Java.

The code:

```
public void nullify() {

        // Set all variables to null. You will be recreating them in the
        // constructor.
        paint = null;
        lives = 0;
        enemies = null;
        boom = null;
        bosses = null;
        canvas = null;
        player = null;

        envi = null;
        spikes= null;
        paint = null;
        mContext = null;
        level = 0;
        score = 0;

        // Call garbage collector to clean up memory.
        System.gc();

    }


    public void updateGameOver() {

                    nullify();
                     Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    return;
                }
```

The idea is to click in the button and go to restart the game.

Comment: hasn't anyone told you that you don't need to call `System.gc()` yourself because the system handles it?

Comment: Offtopic. You don't need `return;` in the end of `updateGameOver()` method because it is the last statement of the "void" method.

Comment: Ok but this is not the answer

Comment: Where exactly u r getting the NPE 
1) @gameView.updateGameOver(); or 2) Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);

Comment: @gameView.updateGameOver()

Comment: Is it full `GameOverDialog` code? You didn't initialize `gameView`, it is null.

Answer (score 1):

mContext is null after you set it null in your the 'nullify()' method.
So:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

will fail.

Comment: I want to restart the game

Comment: @PauloRodrigues don't null mContext cause you'll use it in `updateGameOver()`. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

As simple your `gameView` object is null.  You haven't initialized it.

Also simply call as

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: can you help me? ?

Comment: Show me your GameView class

Comment: what part you want?

Answer (score 0):

You should not do cleanup task in onClick method.  Activity have onStop  and onDestroy method for these kind of task.

Remove nullify() method from updateGameOver method.

When new activity is starting, current activity will go from onStop if next activity obscured the current activity.

```
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            nullify();
    }
    public void updateGameOver() {

     // nullify();
     Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
     mContext.startActivity(intent);
     return;
    }
```